# Will an Australian work visa overstay almost 10 years ago affect my Tier 4 UK visa?

Tags: visas, uk, australia

So I've been agonising over this.

I have just submitted my UK visa application (Tier 4) and have also submitted my current passport as well as my 2 old/expired passports to UKVI for processing.

In one of my old passports is my old Australia work visa that had ceased due to my loss of job (redundancy) in Australia. I overstayed the visa for a bit after I lost my job. I was trying to find another job to stay in Australia and unfortunately time caught up with me. I was never deported but I was asked to leave the country voluntarily or contact Australian Immigration to look at possible visa options that I can apply for while still in Australia. I decided to take the first option and I left Australia voluntarily. This happened almost 10 years ago. I have since then entered Australia numerous times on various different Australian visas. I was never ban from Australia and in fact I currently have a three-year Australia visa.

Anyway, after I submitted all my passports and biometric data I realised I have made the mistake of saying the wrong thing in my online UK visa application. I said "No" when asked "Have you been deported or required to leave any country in the last 10 years?"

Given that I said "No" and yet my old passport contain the old ceased Australia visa, I am now worried this is going to work againts me. There is no "ban" stamp or anything like that on that old visa and old passport. As I said earlier, I left voluntarily with no problems and have been allowed back into Australia many many times. It's just that I said "No" in the application and yet submitted the old passport that contained the ceased visa.

My questions are: 
1) Can the UK visa officers work out that contradiction in my application by just looking at my old passports? 
2) Does UKVI and Australia Immigration have data sharing connection? 
3) Does UKVI actually look at every little detail in old passports, or will they just concentrate on my current passport. I hope they can disregard my old passports and just look at my current one.
4) How long does Australia Immigration keep visa data on file/database
5) Is there a way I can contact UKVI and ammend my application before a decision is reached?
6) What's the likelihood of my visa application being refused and will I be banned from entering UK if my visa application is refused?

Thank you for your help.

Ben

Comment: I am not an expert on this, but I think the people who are will want to know if the Australian Immigration wrote to you requiring you to leave, or merely reminded you that your time was up. Your narrative is a little informal there.