# Does UKVI check other countries visa details on your old passport?

Tags: visas, uk, australia

So I have just applied for a UK visa.

I submitted my old passports as well as my current passport. Does UKVI actually look at every little detail in old passports and visa details from other countries or do they just concentrate on current passport? On on of my old passport is an Australia visa that has ceased long time ago which I have an some issues with. Will UKVI look into that and question it?

Cheers

Ben

Comment: Anecdotally: We've seen a fair number of UK visa refusals posted here, and they contain rather detailed accounts of the ECO's reasoning for denying the application. I don't recall a singe one that even mentioned the presence of other visas or entry stamps in the passport, much less earlier passports.

Comment: However, if you failed to reveal in your application the overstay in Australia and the removal order, per your earlier question, you may have created a huge problem for yourself and the potential of a refusal for deception.

Comment: Giorgio - They asked for my old passports and I couldn't find it when I submitted my online application but by the time I went to do biometrics (a week later) I was able to locate my old passport and I handed it over but there was no way I could amend the application. I asked the person who was collecting the documents if I could amend my application and the person said there's no time and took all my documents and sent me off. The old passport has old visa in it which I had forgotten all details of it until I located it. The old visa issue is almost 10 years ago.

Comment: @Ben Did you make any mention at all of your previous visa problem in the application? Doesn’t sound like something easily ‘forgotten’ despite the passage of time, even without full details it would have been better to at least mention it

Comment: Bottom line is ECOs and other consular officers will take advantage of whatever immigration history you provide to them. I mean don’t you expect that if the old passport fell open and they noticed you had a deportation stamp from another country on there (or some other negative) they wouldn’t take it into account? So to answer I don’t believe they go scouring your old passport for stuff but they definitely will make note if they come across it.

Answer (score 3):

In coming to a decision, all factors are evaluated as to how an applicant meets visa eligibility criteria. Those include all travel and immigration history, both beneficial and unfavorable.

From what you discuss in [your earlier question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/117976/will-an-australian-work-visa-overstay-almost-10-years-ago-affect-my-tier-4-uk-vi), what occurred nearly 10 years ago is no longer an issue. Australia has seen fit to grant you subsequent visas, including a current long-term visa.

With such a positive record, UKVI may not even view it as a factor at this point; should it arise, you just explain the circumstances.